# predict numpy array datatype after array calculations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

How can I predict the datatype of the resulting array after combining two arrays of certain datatypes, without actually performing the calculation? E.g.

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([0.5, 0.1, 1.3, 1.5]).astype(np.float32)
arr2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).astype(np.uint8)
arr3 = np.array([-10, 2, 3, 4, 120]).astype(np.int8)

output_dtype1 = np.multiply(arr1, arr2).dtype  # np.float32

output_dtype2 = np.multiply(arr2, arr3).dtype  # np.int16
```

Would it be possible to write a function that returns `output_dtype1` and `output_dtype2`, using `arr1.dtype`, `arr2.dtype`, `arr3.dtype` and the array operator (`multiply`, `add`, `subtract` etc) as arguments ?

Comment: If the arrays aren't too large the actual calculation is probably fastest.  `ufunc` do have signature information, but using that with python level calls is probably slower.

Comment: Study https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#casting-rules

Comment: My arrays are not necessarily large. My use-case is writing geospatial rasters to file using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), for which the output profile has to be compiled beforehand.

Comment: For future reference, I've also found the rasterio [dtype module](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.dtypes.html), especially the [get_minimum_dtype](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.dtypes.html#rasterio.dtypes.get_minimum_dtype) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on reading https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#casting-rules

I tried:

```
In [196]: np.result_type(np.float32, np.uint8)
Out[196]: dtype('float32')
In [197]: np.result_type(np.int8, np.uint8)
Out[197]: dtype('int16')
```